# Struts2 configuration - together in xml and annotations. Possible?

Tags: struts2, web-config, annotations

I have never used annotations in Struts2.

But now, while going through some hibernate annotations tutorials, I got this question in my mind.
Is it possible that in Struts2 I can use both annotations and xml for configuring my action classes? i.e. **is it possible that I can configure some of my action classes in struts.xml and rest of them using annotations**?

I will anyway try to code this when I'll get a chance (right now, using a system with no IDE and slow internet). Is there anybody else who has tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes dude I have tried and it worked pretty well. I had done it in the beginning of my struts learning assignments where i tried doing many things into single project and I did configure some of my action classes in struts.xml and rest of them using annotations.
You can try when you will get chance, It works 100%. Dont worry :)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me as well.  You have to remember to not set the `config` parameter for your `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.  Instead, make sure that the struts.xml file is in the `/WEB-INF/classes` directory of your WAR.

If you do accidentally set the `config` parameter of the servlet filter `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`, your parameter `actionPackages` will get ignored.